# while function in postgresql not working

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql

i have 3 tables, tblAnalyse, tblSubAnalyse, tblResault

tblAnalyse: 
id integer,
name text,
isParent bool,

tblSubAnalyse:
id integer,
analyseId integer,
name text,

tblResault:
id integer,
analyseId integer,
subAnaliseId integer,
accountId integer,
Analysedate date,

Ok now when the isParent in table tblAnalyse  is True i want to insert the subAnalysis to result,  I wrote Function but it does n't work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION year_2014.insertsubanalysis
(
  accountid      integer,
  analyseid      integer,
  analysedate    date,
  requestnumber  integer
)
RETURNS record AS
$$
DECLARE 
i INTEGER;
AnalyseCount INTEGER;
SubAnalyseId INTEGER;
begin
i := 1;
SELECT public."SubAnalyze".id into SubAnalyseId FROM  public."SubAnalyze" where public."SubAnalyze".analyze_id = analyseid;
SELECT count(public."SubAnalyze".id) into AnalyseCount FROM  public."SubAnalyze" where public."SubAnalyze".analyze_id = analyseid;
WHILE(i <= AnalyseCount) loop
   INSERT INTO year_2014."Results"(account_id, analyze_id, "date", subanalyze_id, requestnumber)
VALUES
    (accountid, analyseid, 'analysedate', SubAnalyseId, requestnumber);
END LOOP;
RETURN 1; 
end
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION year_2014.insertsubanalysis(accountid integer, analyseid integer, analysedate date, requestnumber integer)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work". How **exactly** does it not work? Describe what happens or does not happen. Show the **exact text** of any error messages. Please *edit your question* to add this information, don't put it in comments. Then comment here when done. While you're at it, show your PostgreSQL version - `SELECT version()`.

Answer (score 0):

when I run the function:

SQL Error: ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM year_2014.insertsubanalysis(7, 14, '12/12/2014...
                      ^